# How to load different scripts for different state in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently I want to load different scripts for english and hebrew language in the state. But the hebrew script is not getting rendered even when the redux useSelector value is changed to hebrew. It always show the English button in the right side . Now my code looks like

```
function HeadCustom({ title }) {
  const { lang } = useSelector((state) => state.language.language);
  const isEng = () => {
    return lang === "eng";
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isEng() ? (
          <Script>
            {`window.interdeal = { "sitekey": "216e47f62cb419bc8207601b49e6dbc6", "Position": "Right", "Menulang": "EN", "domains": { "js": "https://cdn.equalweb.com/", "acc": "https://access.equalweb.com/" }, "btnStyle": { "vPosition": ["80%", null], "scale": ["0.6", "0.6"], "color": { "main": "#5663eb" }, "icon": { "type": 11, "shape": "semicircle", "outline": false } } }; (function (doc, head, body) { var coreCall = doc.createElement('script'); coreCall.src = 'https://cdn.equalweb.com/core/4.4.0/accessibility.js'; coreCall.defer = true; coreCall.integrity = 'sha512-3lGJBcuai1J0rGJHJj4e4lYOzm7K08oEHsg1Llt7x24OOsa/Ca0wwbSi9HhWUn92FKN3fylaq9xmIKVZnUsT3Q=='; coreCall.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; coreCall.setAttribute('data-cfasync', true); body ? body.appendChild(coreCall) : head.appendChild(coreCall); })(document, document.head, document.body);`}
          </Script>
      ) : (
          <Script>
            {`window.interdeal = { "sitekey": "b1deb4b25a71a4e1d747032724407d56", "Position": "Right", "Menulang": "HEB", "domains": { "js": "https://cdn.equalweb.com/", "acc": "https://access.equalweb.com/" }, "btnStyle": { "vPosition": ["80%", null], "scale": ["0.8", "0.8"], "color": { "main": "#5663eb" }, "icon": { "type": 11, "shape": "semicircle", "outline": false } } }; (function (doc, head, body) { var coreCall = doc.createElement('script'); coreCall.src = 'https://cdn.equalweb.com/core/4.4.1/accessibility.js'; coreCall.defer = true; coreCall.integrity = 'sha512-tq2wb4PBHqpUqBTfTG32Sl7oexERId9xGHX2O3yF91IYLII2OwM1gJVBXGbEPaLmfSQrIE+uAOzNOuEUZHHM+g=='; coreCall.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; coreCall.setAttribute('data-cfasync', true); body ? body.appendChild(coreCall) : head.appendChild(coreCall); })(document, document.head, document.body);`}
          </Script>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see the script language in the Menulang property

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a `<script>` element dynamically.

Depending on your actual needs, I'd suggest

- load the required data with [`fetch(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) *(instead of `<script src="...">`)*, or
- use `router.replace` when changing the language, and use e.g. [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) to create the data for the `<script>` elements, or
- use the [Next.js built-in i18n support](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)

### Details:

You can *add* a `<script>` element, but you can never remove it, or more precisely: You can remove the element, but you can never make the script "not have been executed".

The general way to use React / Next.js would be more like this:

```
useEffect( () => {
    window.interdeal = {
        Menulang: lang,
        sitekey: ...
        ...
    }   
}, [ lang ] );
```

Also you should never manipulate the DOM manually when working with React (as you do with e.g. `body.appendChild`). If you need to do that anyway, you have to do it inside a `useEffect`.